# iterate two values in for loop in bash

Tags: bash

I have a function in bash that creates volumes and then attaches them to a newly created aws instance.

I need to ask the user how many volumes to create, and then attach it to the instance with this line:

```
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id "${volumes[i]}" --instance-id "$tag_instance_id" --device "$device" --profile="$aws_key"
```

I am using a loop to iterate through the volumes that are created. I need to assign a device to the instance with would be of the form:

```
/dev/xvdf
```

Then the next volume would be /dev/xvdg, /dev/xvdf depending on how many the user asks for.

This is the loop I've created:

```
  printf "Number of volumes to add: "
  read -r num_volumes
  volumes=()
  for (( i=0; i < num_volumes; i++ )); do
    ...do stuff...
   aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id "${volumes[i]}" --instance-id "$tag_instance_id" --device "$device" --profile="$aws_key"
  done
```

How do I iterate among both the number of volume ($i) and the device values from /dev/xvd{f..z} in the same line? The volume number ($i) has to correspond to the device name (/dev/xvdf or whatever).

Comment: `devices=( /dev/xvdb{f..z} )` and then you have another array you can index into: `"${devices[$i]}"`, just the same as you refer to `"${volumes[$i]}"`

Comment: Ok, that's great. Thank you! I will work on this.

Comment: Hey Charles Duffy.. tried that. Worked perfectly. Thanks again!